# Segmentation fault when the first number is deleted

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

The problem is when I delete the first number of the list, I can delete anyone, but if I delete the first one, a segmentation fault appears. Did I write the insert or the delete function wrongly (or both)?

```
int insert_values(list *l, int value){
  node *new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if(!new_node) return 1; /*verify if the node was created*/
  new_node->key = value;
  new_node->next = l->head;
  l->head = new_node;
  return 0;
}

void del(list *l, int value){
  node *p = l->head, *q;
  while(p != NULL && p->key != value){
    q = p;
    p = p->next;
  }
  q->next = p->next;
  free(p);
}
```

Comment: If you delete the first node, you need to change `l->head` to point to the second node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep a *pointer-to-pointer* to the current node as you iterate over your list to find the node to delete, you do not have to worry about any special cases such as whether you are deleting the head node. For example:

```
/** delete node with value v from list (for loop) */
void del_node (list *l, int v)
{
    node **ppn = &l->head;      /* pointer to pointer */
    node *pn = l->head;         /* pointer to node */

    for (; pn; ppn = &pn->next, pn = pn->next) {
        if (pn->data == v) {
            *ppn = pn->next;    /* set address to next */
            free (pn);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This eliminates special cases because `ppn` holds the *address of* the node to be deleted. Assigning a new pointer to the address of the node does not change the node address, only its content eliminating the need to check whether the node is your first node. Explained more fully in [Linus on understanding pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

This presumes you are using a setup like:

```
typedef struct node {       /* list node */
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct {            /* list wrapper with head & tail pointers */
    node *head, *tail;
} list;
```

(which from your question it is apparent you are)

Comment: Glad it helped. Linked lists are the perfect tool for learning pointers before moving on the btrees, etc.. Understanding that you can use the address of the pointer and just change the contents there rather than having to change where your list starts is as good a place as any to learn the address of the pointer can be just as useful as the contents it holds. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: You may also find [Singly Linked List of Integers](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the first node, you need to change the `head` to point to the node after it. Otherwise, you'll continue to try to use the node that was freed.

```
void del(list *l, int value){
  node *p = l->head, *q;
  while(p != NULL && p->key != value){
    q = p;
    p = p->next;
  }
  q->next = p->next;
  if (p == l->head) {
    // Change head to point to next node
    l->head = p->next;
  }
  free(p);
}
```